# Sorting 2d object array Java

Tags: java, arrays, 2d, bubble-sort

I have an object array with customers. Every customer has max number of wishes.
I have:

```
Customer[] customer  = new Customer[numOfCustomers]
C_wishes [][] w = new C_wishes[numOfCustomers] [maxWishes]
```

I sorted the out the customers with bubble sort but I can't do it the same with 2d array. Basically i would like to do something like this

```
[[obj7,o8, o9],[o1,o2,o3],[o4,o5,o6]] => [[obj1,o2, o3],[o4,o5,o6],[o7,o8,o9]]
```

but at some point the wishes don't align with customers.
I'll post the code as soon as I can.

Comment: Show us the code that didn't work for you. **Hint**: You need to sort only the `w[][]` array.

Comment: As soon as i get to my computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(If you don't want to use HashMaps)
Just create a temp 2d array, the sort each sub-array (meaning sort all `temp[i]`) based on the first value in the sub-array (meaning based on `temp[i][0]`).

Answer (score 0):

Id use a HashMap. Maps and Lists usually have sorting functions built in.

You need to know how to use 1.8 Lambdas tho